# How to work with dynamic subdomains in ASP.NET Core 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, subdomain

I want to create a blog website like blogger.com 
I use ASP.NET Core 5 and visual studio 2019.
When I use kestrel everything is fine and this url test.localhost5001 is work correctly, but I want to use IIS and now this url test.localhost44324 doesn't work and I get error 400 (Bad Request - Invalid Hostname ). How can I work with dynamic subdomains in IIS express ?

I repeat I want to work with dynamic subdomains not limited number subdomains.

Comment: If you use full IIS, then suitable site bindings can allow all kinds of traffic to be handled. However, IIS Express by default only allows `localhost` traffic, and it is doable but not that easy to allow all traffic (any subdomain).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working is because IIS Express doesn't accept connections to a host with a header other than localhost, as per the comments.

There is a way to do what you want, you can use our free VS Extension called [Conveyor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti) which proxies connections to IIS Express.  That will mean that you can send requests to the Conveyor port and IIS Express will think that the request is to localhost.

For most users that is enough, but you want to send traffic to subdomains, to do that you can send traffic to the Conveyor Remote URL port, eg.

```
https://subdomain.localhost:45455
https://subdomain2.localhost:45455
```

When your code runs, you will see that the request's Location header is just "localhost", which is not that useful for you, but look at the Forwarded header and you will see "subdomain.localhost" in there, and from that you can do what you need.